# Desktop уведомление о изменениях в TFS

Tags: visual-studio, контроль-версий, tfs

Пользуюсь TFS и приходится очень часто обновлять страницу с Набором изменений(check-in), что бы всегда быть в курсе последних изменений.

Можно ли как то настроить TFS, что бы уведомления приходили в Desktop? На email уже делал, но не удобно...

Comment: а у Вас что, чужие изменения попадают к Вам в ветку на вашем ПК? (именно не зачекиненные изменения)

Comment: Нет, но хотелось бы узнавать о всех изменениях push уведомлением, а не через браузер или visual studio.

Comment: если у меня на работе включить уведомления о всех изменениях, то я наверное с ума сойду от этих уведомлений. Подобное встречал - настройка уведомлений о сборке после каждого чекина. Но это не то, что Вам нужно, а лишь похожая форма оповещения.

Comment: Если Вы зайдете в папку: *C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE*, то там найдете файл **BuildNotificationApp.exe**. Это и есть десктопная уведомлялка о сборке. Я настраивал у себя на работе BuildServer и это то, чем многие пользуются. К примеру я всегда знаю после чьего чекина у меня упал проект. Вы можете использовать это в своих нуждах, к примеру ничего не билдить, а просто уведомлять о чекине.

Comment: Собственно говоря, других идей нет. По крайней мере это то, что хоть как-то приближает Вас к желаемому результату. Да, на мыло или же в браузере следить за изменениями не удобно. Будем смотреть на ответы, может у кого-то есть решение

Comment: Можно сделать слегка по другому: Подписаться на обновление TFS -> Desktop Email (Например Outlook) -> Desktop Уведомление) Думаю, такой вариант тоже прокатит.

Comment: У меня сейчас похожая настройка, но только на бэклоги, баги и таски. У нас в отделе разработки много программистов и если подписаться на все чекины, то уведомления просто задолбают :)